# Why I can't add left bar button item to Navigation Item through Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone

It only allows me to add the right barbutton, but when I drag another barbuttonitem, it's simply denied.
I looked at the properties of NavigationItem, and I saw that there are outlets for right barbutton and even for the back barbutton. 
So: why can't I add a left barbutton item to the Navigation Item (through Interface Builder)?

Comment: It might be because the back button is there? Have you tried doing it programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, using it programatically is probably (way) better. 
Use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:<otherviewname> animated:YES];`
This way, in the next view, there is a backbutton to this screen added automatically (unless you decide to hide the backbutton programatically in that next view, but that's a whole different story). 
The advantage of pushViewController instead of modalTransitionView is that navigation-options are so easily added!

Comment: the problem is that I setup my Navigation Item by myself (it's not pretty comfortable to set stuff like color, shadows from code).

Comment: how about using: `- (void)viewDidLoad {     [super viewDidLoad];     UIBarButtonItem     *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init]; self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(backToPreviousScreen:)];  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton; self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES; } ` ? It makes sure the leftbutton does what u want it to do, but the rest is still editable in the IB.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot add a button to a Navigation Bar if it is defined in the View properties, however if you add a Navigation Bar from the Object Library you can add buttons (left and right).